# How to select rows in a list that have e.g. their nth element meeting a criterion?

Tags: list-manipulation

Let `a` be a list of lists like this:

```
a= {{"apples", "pears", 1, 17},
    {"pineapples", "apples", 5, 7},
    {"yes", "building", 4, 7}}
```

How can I make a list `b` containing only elements of `a` for which the nth element meets an arbitrary criterion?

Let us say for example that n is 3 and the criterion is "must be greater than 2". Then `b` would be

```
{{"pineapples", "apples", 5, 7},
    {"yes", "building", 4, 7}}.
```

Answer (score 2):

No sooner do I post the question than I think I've found the answer!

```
 b = Select[a, #[[3]] > 2 &]
```

Comment: Also `Cases[a, {_, _, n_, ___} /; n > 2]`

Comment: @MelaGo - Thanks for this. Your version is more widely useful because Cases can match strings and numbers, whereas Select matches numbers only.

Comment: You're welcome. You can use `Select` with any expression that evaluates to `True`, for example  `Select[a, #[[2]] == "apples" &]` or `Select[a, StringMatchQ[#[[2]], "apples"] &]`