# How to prune from a list every element which doesn't share e.g. both its 1st and 2nd elements with SOME element in a specified other list?

Tags: list-manipulation

This is a followup question to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/291726/how-to-select-rows-in-a-list-that-have-e-g-their-nth-element-meeting-a-criterio).

Let `a` and `b` be lists of lists like this:

```
a= {{"apples", "pears", 1, 17},
{"pineapples", "apples", 5, 7},
{"yes", "building", 4, 7},
{"no","camel","rabbit",0}}
  
b= {{"man", 1, 2, 17},
{"pineapples", "apples", "cow", "yes"},
{"no","camel","carpet","wibble"},
{"yes", "buildings", 4, 7}}
```

How can I remove from `b` every row that doesn't share both its 1st and its 2nd elements, say, in that order and in those specific slots, with any of the rows in `a`?

Once they've been deleted in this example, `b` would become

```
 b= { {"pineapples", "apples", "cow", "yes"},
{"no","camel","carpet","wibble"}}
```

As far as I can tell, ∈ can't be used to define a criterion in `Cases`.

Comment: Maybe `Select[b, ! FreeQ[a[[All, 1 ;; 2]], #[[1 ;; 2]]] &]`

Comment: Thanks, but that only picks up the "pineapples" element and misses the "no" one.

Comment: I guess that's because the comma is missing after the 3rd element in the definition of b

Comment: Ah yes. You are right! It works fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select[b, MemberQ[a[[All, {1, 2}]], #[[{1, 2}]]] &]
```

Comment: Yes. Got it. This works fine now, as also does @vindobona's suggestion. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
Intersection[b, a, SameTest -> (#[[;; 2]] == #2[[;; 2]] &)]
```

> ```
> {{"no", "camel", "carpet", "wibble"},   
>  {"pineapples", "apples", "cow", "yes"}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cases[{a_, _} :> Flatten @ a] @
 GatherBy[MapApply[{{#1, #2}, {##3}} &] @ Join[b, a], First]
```

{{"pineapples", "apples", "cow", "yes"}, {"no", "camel", "carpet",
"wibble"}}

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {{"apples", "pears", 1, 17}, {"pineapples", "apples", 5, 
   7}, {"yes", "building", 4, 7}, {"no", "camel", "rabbit", 0}}
b = {{"man", 1, 2, 17}, {"pineapples", "apples", "cow", "yes"}, {"no",
    "camel", "carpet", "wibble"}, {"yes", "buildings", 4, 7}}

d1 = #[[1 ;; 2]] -> #[[3 ;;]] & /@ a;
d2 = #[[1 ;; 2]] -> #[[3 ;;]] & /@ b;

KeySelect[d2, KeyMemberQ[d1, #] &] // KeyValueMap[Flatten@*List]
```

> {{"pineapples", "apples", "cow", "yes"}, {"no", "camel", "carpet",
> "wibble"}}